# Catch Session before using CURL

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies

I am trying to login into a form using CURL. The CURL seems to work fine but I noticed, using Chrome Console, that the form deny to proceed if a session is not already started. I explain: when I open the form page, I see that a cookie called JSESSIONID has been created, and if I delete it the form deny to proceed with the login and redirects on the form page to create the session.

So the question is, can I create a session and get the JSESSIONID before using CURL?

If anyone wants to try, the page is:

https://service.threadvine.eu/account/login

and go on Console -> Resources -> Cookies to see the JSESSIONID cookie.

Thank you all!

Comment: Use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, GET the login page first, then POST the form using the same curl handle. Curl will remember the session cookie set by the response to the first request and automatically send it with the second one.

Comment: Thank you! Aswered under here, too long to post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make curl handle cookies, use curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true); - 
i do not have an account, so i can't actually test past getting "login failed", but i think this should work, with a valid $login_email / $login_password. notice how i make an empty request before trying to log in, this is just to get the session ID (JSESSIONID). - and i have assumed that if the cookie "RememberMe" is "deleteMe", the login failed - again, i cannot verify this without a valid account, but it sounds logical. they respond with a "HTTP 200 OK" even though login failed, while they SHOULD give a "HTTP 401 Unauthorized" or similar, shame on them.

also, there's no  need to use my hhb_ functions (at several 100's of lines), they just make it easier to debug curl sessions

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $login_email='login_email@gmail.com';
    $login_password='pass';
    $headers=array();
    $cookies=array();
    $debuginfo="";
    $ch=hhb_curl_init(array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36'));
    $html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://service.threadvine.eu/account/login',$headers,$cookies,$debuginfo);
    //^getting a session id etc.
    //var_dump('$headers:',$headers,'$cookies:',$cookies,'$debuginfo:',$debuginfo,'$html',$html);
    $login_str=http_build_query(array(
    'targetUri'=>'',
    'email'=>$login_email,
    'password'=>$login_password,
    '_rememberMe'=>'',
    'submit'=>'Login'
    ));
    assert(is_string($login_str));
    assert(curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$login_str
    )));
    $html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://service.threadvine.eu/account/login',$headers,$cookies,$debuginfo);
    if($cookies['rememberMe']==='deleteMe'){
        echo "FAILED TO LOG IN! (probably) - got the deleteMe cookie!";
        }
var_dump('$headers:',$headers,'$cookies:',$cookies,'$debuginfo:',$debuginfo,'$html',$html);



    function hhb_curl_init($custom_options_array = array())
{
    if (empty($custom_options_array)) {
        $custom_options_array = array();
        //i feel kinda bad about this.. argv[1] of curl_init wants a string(url), or NULL
        //at least i want to allow NULL aswell :/
    }
    if (!is_array($custom_options_array)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$custom_options_array must be an array!');
    }
    ;
    $options_array = array(
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 11,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => ""
        //CURLOPT_REFERER=>'example.org',
        //CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'
    );
    if (!array_key_exists(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $custom_options_array)) {
        //do this only conditionally because tmpfile() call..
        static $curl_cookiefiles_arr = array(); //workaround for https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66014
        $curl_cookiefiles_arr[]            = $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = tmpfile();
        $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = stream_get_meta_data($options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE]);
        $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE]['uri'];

    }
    //we can't use array_merge() because of how it handles integer-keys, it would/could cause corruption
    foreach ($custom_options_array as $key => $val) {
        $options_array[$key] = $val;
    }
    unset($key, $val, $custom_options_array);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options_array);
    return $curl;
}
function hhb_curl_exec($ch, $url)
{
    static $hhb_curl_domainCache = "";
    //$hhb_curl_domainCache=&$this->hhb_curl_domainCache;
    //$ch=&$this->curlh;
    if (!is_resource($ch) || get_resource_type($ch) !== 'curl') {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$ch must be a curl handle!');
    }
    if (!is_string($url)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$url must be a string!');
    }

    $tmpvar = "";
    if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) === null) {
        if (substr($url, 0, 1) !== '/') {
            $url = $hhb_curl_domainCache . '/' . $url;
        } else {
            $url = $hhb_curl_domainCache . $url;
        }
    }
    ;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        throw new Exception('Curl error (curl_errno=' . curl_errno($ch) . ') on url ' . var_export($url, true) . ': ' . curl_error($ch));
        // echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    if ($html === '' && 203 != ($tmpvar = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) /*203 is "success, but no output"..*/ ) {
        throw new Exception('Curl returned nothing for ' . var_export($url, true) . ' but HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE was ' . var_export($tmpvar, true));
    }
    ;
    //remember that curl (usually) auto-follows the "Location: " http redirects..
    $hhb_curl_domainCache = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL), PHP_URL_HOST);
    return $html;
}
function hhb_curl_exec2($ch, $url, &$returnHeaders = array(), &$returnCookies = array(), &$verboseDebugInfo = "")
{
    $returnHeaders    = array();
    $returnCookies    = array();
    $verboseDebugInfo = "";
    if (!is_resource($ch) || get_resource_type($ch) !== 'curl') {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$ch must be a curl handle!');
    }
    if (!is_string($url)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$url must be a string!');
    }
    $verbosefileh = tmpfile();
    $verbosefile  = stream_get_meta_data($verbosefileh);
    $verbosefile  = $verbosefile['uri'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbosefileh);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $html             = hhb_curl_exec($ch, $url);
    $verboseDebugInfo = file_get_contents($verbosefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, NULL);
    fclose($verbosefileh);
    unset($verbosefile, $verbosefileh);
    $headers       = array();
    $crlf          = "\x0d\x0a";
    $thepos        = strpos($html, $crlf . $crlf, 0);
    $headersString = substr($html, 0, $thepos);
    $headerArr     = explode($crlf, $headersString);
    $returnHeaders = $headerArr;
    unset($headersString, $headerArr);
    $htmlBody = substr($html, $thepos + 4); //should work on utf8/ascii headers... utf32? not so sure..
    unset($html);
    //I REALLY HOPE THERE EXIST A BETTER WAY TO GET COOKIES.. good grief this looks ugly..
    //at least it's tested and seems to work perfectly...
    $grabCookieName = function($str,&$len)
    {
        $len=0;
        $ret = "";
        $i   = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i) {
            ++$len;
            if ($str[$i] === ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            if ($str[$i] === '=') {
                --$len;
                break;
            }
            $ret .= $str[$i];
        }
        return urldecode($ret);
    };
    foreach ($returnHeaders as $header) {
        //Set-Cookie: crlfcoookielol=crlf+is%0D%0A+and+newline+is+%0D%0A+and+semicolon+is%3B+and+not+sure+what+else
        /*Set-Cookie:ci_spill=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22305d3d67b8016ca9661c3b032d4319df%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%2285.164.158.128%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A109%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F43.0.2357.132+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1436874639%3B%7Dcab1dd09f4eca466660e8a767856d013; expires=Tue, 14-Jul-2015 13:50:39 GMT; path=/
        Set-Cookie: sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT;
        //Cookie names cannot contain any of the following '=,; \t\r\n\013\014'
        //
        */
        if (stripos($header, "Set-Cookie:") !== 0) {
            continue;
            /**/
        }
        $header = trim(substr($header, strlen("Set-Cookie:")));
        $len=0;
        while (strlen($header) > 0) {
            $cookiename                 = $grabCookieName($header,$len);
            $returnCookies[$cookiename] = '';
            $header                     = substr($header, $len + 1); //also remove the = 
            if (strlen($header) < 1) {
                break;
            }
            ;
            $thepos = strpos($header, ';');
            if ($thepos === false) { //last cookie in this Set-Cookie.
                $returnCookies[$cookiename] = urldecode($header);
                break;
            }
            $returnCookies[$cookiename] = urldecode(substr($header, 0, $thepos));
            $header                     = trim(substr($header, $thepos + 1)); //also remove the ;
        }
    }
    unset($header, $cookiename, $thepos);
    return $htmlBody;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine! Remember_me cookie is not catching the login ok or failure but the rest works really fine. Now I've only to study how and why it works! :) Thank you man!